# Regex search list of emails

Tags: regular-expression

So I have a long list of email and I want to search these based on just a few sections of the email string.

I want to try and search these emails more efficently so I want to match the start of the email. Is there a simple way to match the first character/first few characters, the @ and the following character and end of the email.

Here's an example search:

```
cal****@a**m
```

So then if I used a search on the following list it would only pull the top 2

```
callum@aol.com
callumsmith@aol.com
callumfrrg@test.com
someemail@test.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
grep '^cal.*@a.*m$' input.txt
```

This matches lines beginning `^` with `cal`, followed by anything (`.*`), followed by `@a`, again followed by anything, with `m` at the end (`$`).

Comment: `grep -x` would get rid of the need for explicit anchors.